# Prove that the order of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{{F}_{p}})$ is $p^{4}-p^{3}-p^{2}+p$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that the order of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{{F}_{p}})$ is $p^{4}-p^{3}-p^{2}+p$.

I know that the matrix $2\times 2$ is given by this formula

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} = ad-bc.$$

I know that the determinant is going to be zero whenever $ad=bc$.

Thank you.

Comment: **Hint** How many vectors in $\Bbb F_p^2$ can be the first column of a vector in $GL_2(\Bbb F_p)$?

Comment: I believe it should be 2

Comment: Even for $p = 2$, there are three possibilities: $\pmatrix{0\\1}$, $\pmatrix{1\\0}$, and $\pmatrix{1\\1}$.